# Call two relational tables in a singe id in Laravel. (check photos)

Tags: php, laravel, api, laravel-5

I am trying to combine the below responses into a single entry

[image]

Here i got two keys but how i will make it in a single key.

[image]

In my controller i specified id for two different resources for author and authorprofile. But how can i use with single resourse because author and author profile is in relationship tables.

[image]

The resource attributes in the screenshot please check.

[image]

Comment: You have to create a relationship in your model and after that call it inside to your resource file.

Comment: How to call it inside the resource can you help

Comment: Example if you have relationships as authorProfile() in the Author.php then you can call like this inside of your resource

$this->authorProfile

Comment: Hello, please read the stackoverflow guide about [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It says `DO NOT use images of code`. Welcome to stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey its better to use Eloquent Relation like if you have `Author` Model and `AuthorProfile` Model so you put below method in Author model

```
public function Authorprofile(){
return $this->belongsTo(AuthorProfile::class, 'authorprofile_id');
}
```

then use in Controller like.

```
public function show($id){
 $author = Author::with('Authorprofile')->find($id)
}
```

Hope it mights help

Comment: I think also need some changes on Resource file of author can you check!!

Comment: please refer this link for additional changes 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-resources